# How to check whether ScrollView is scrollable

Tags: android

I was wondering, how to check whether the current `ScrollView` is scrollable? It seems that, there isn't public method called `canScroll` or `isScrollable` in `ScrollView`.

**Scrollable** : You can move the ViewGroup inside the ScrollView up and down, and the scroll bar will be visible when you move it up and down. So, if there is only little rows in the `ScrollView`, and they can fit inside single screen, `ScrollView` is not scrollable then.

Comment: Scrollable - You can move the ViewGroup inside the ScrollView up and down, and the scroll bar will be visible when you move it up and down.

Comment: that's what a scrollview is about, i don't get your question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do some little math to calculate the views raw height and the height of the content. If the difference of this heights is < 0 the view is scrollable.

To calculate the raw height you can use [View.getMeasuredHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight%28%29).
Because ScrollView is a ViewGroup and has max one child, get the height of that child with [ViewGroup.getChildAt(0).getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29);

Use a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) to get the heights, because it will be called at the moment the layout / view is changing the visibility, otherwise the heights could be 0.

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id...);
ViewTreeObserver observer = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int viewHeight = scrollView.getMeasuredHeight();
        int contentHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        if(viewHeight - contentHeight < 0) {
            // scrollable
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason using scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(); and not scrollView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight();

Comment: @CheokYanCheng In this case there is no difference between this methods. As I tested it the values are equal. But if you change the layout params in Java code use getHeight() to be sure, the right values return.

Answer (score 5):

```
scrollView.viewTreeObserver
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener {

            val isScrollable = scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be missing something, but shouldn't it be as simple as checking if

```
scrollView.getHeight() >= parentView.getMeasuredHeight()
```

you might actually need: `scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()` and/or `parentView.getHeight()` instead, but the idea is the same.