# check if an android scrollview can scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

Do you know if it is possible to know if an Android Widget ScrollView can scroll?
If it has enough space it doesn't need to scroll, but as soon as a dimension exceeds a maximum value the widget can scroll.

I don't see in the reference a method who can give this information.
Maybe is it possible to do something with the size of the linearlayout inside the scrollview?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18574328/3571822, it should help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263053/android-scrollview-onscrollchanged

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I used the following code inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574328/3439686 and it works!

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
int childHeight = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollContent)).getHeight();
boolean isScrollable = scrollView.getHeight() < childHeight + scrollView.getPaddingTop() + scrollView.getPaddingBottom();
```

Comment: additional comment: it works when view created and displayed. it's not possible to use in onCreate (for ex: getHeight will return 0, for match_parent)

Comment: The answer is correct, but the method should be called after view created. Check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503573/how-to-check-whether-scrollview-is-scrollable

Answer (score 28):

Thanks to: @johanvs and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574328/3439686

```
private boolean canScroll(HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView) {
    View child = (View) horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0);
    if (child != null) {
        int childWidth = (child).getWidth();
        return horizontalScrollView.getWidth() < childWidth + horizontalScrollView.getPaddingLeft() + horizontalScrollView.getPaddingRight();
    }
    return false;

}

private boolean canScroll(ScrollView scrollView) {
    View child = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
    if (child != null) {
        int childHeight = (child).getHeight();
        return scrollView.getHeight() < childHeight + scrollView.getPaddingTop() + scrollView.getPaddingBottom();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @johanvs response:

You should wait for view beign displayed

```
 final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();

    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            int childHeight = ((LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.dataContent)).getHeight();
            boolean isScrollable = scrollView.getHeight() < childHeight + scrollView.getPaddingTop() + scrollView.getPaddingBottom();
            if (isScrollable) {
                //Urrah! is scrollable
            }
        }
    });
```