# Check if NestedScrollView is Scrollable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, android-scroll

I need a function which returns a boolean if my screen is scrollable inside a NestedScrollView. I currently have a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView and the content of the RecyclerView is dynamic (i can add or remove items). Everytime i swipe to delete i want to call the function which checks if the NestedScrollView is scrollable. I am currently using this function:

```
fun isRecyclerScrollable(binding: FragmentToBuyBinding): Boolean {
    val e = requireActivity().findViewById<NestedScrollView>(R.id.nested)
    return e.canScrollVertically(1) || e.canScrollVertically(-1)
}
```

This works but with a flaw. Upon deleting the last content in my RecyclerView which makes the screen not scrollable, the function still returns true. However, after that, every deletion i perform, it returns false. But this is not good and i need it to return false the moment my screen is not scrollable. Can you help ?

Comment: Can you add the swipe to delete function as well

Comment: The isScrollable function is called after completion of a coroutine. It is inside an Observable livedata, not the swipe function. Can you please help ?

Comment: Pls advise what is the purpose of knowing NestedScrollView is scrollable? It sounds confusing.

Comment: To hide/show a certain view. I just need to know if there is a better way to perform this type of function than my function above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to adapt this answer [check if an android scrollview can scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990992/check-if-an-android-scrollview-can-scroll) to your needs (by replacing ScrollView with NestedScrollView). Surely this will only work once views are rendered.

Comment: Thank you, where should i call it ? (Since in onCreate, getHeight() will return 0)

Comment: I would suggest calling it, for example, after your RecyclerView change happens (e.g., item removal or addition)

Comment: I know what's causing the problem. It is returning true on the first time because this function is running before the view of the recyclerview is being cleared. Is there a way to run this function after the recyclerview's view has been cleared ?